# How long does it take to add a new field to a copyField in Solr?

Tags: solr

I have default search field in my Solr Schema called "text". It is actually a copy field containing six other fields. What I just did is added another multi-value text field to it called "comments", that would be seventh field in "text".

After modifying schema.xml I did "reload core" operation, but after about half an hour I still cannot search in comments by default. Specifying field comments field explicitly in the query works, but it also worked before. Does it take a long time to add and new field to copyField so it gets picked up? Will it re-index all existing documents? Is "reload core" enough or should I do complete Solr bounce?

Answer (score 3):

The "reload core" operation will pick up your schema.xml changes, but you also need to re-index your documents so that the copyField operation takes effect.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but what do you mean "I need to re-index"? Remove all documents and reinsert?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Provided you have a unique id in place, you do not need to remove docs, as these will be overwritten by the new documents with the same id.